# How can i get the label control for a input control by bootstrap in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">TIN</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
     <input class="form-control disable" tabindex="3" id="tin" type="text" placeholder="Enter TIN">
```

So how can I set the css for the lable TIN by jquery ... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean how do you assign the label to the input? It would target the id:

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="tin">TIN</label>
```